# Unknown error creating a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just came back to google's cloud platform and tools to work on a new project after not having touched my account for 9 months or so. The account has billing information. I just accepted the $300, 2 month trial on my account. Now, when I attempt to create new projects (in any and every way I have tried), I get a notification that says "Unknown error." The notification also provides a 'RETRY' option, which produces a new notification for the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the issue has to do with the project name or id. I appear to be able to create projects, just not using the names I would prefer as there is something about having the string '-dot-' in the name or id that throws an unknown error. I'll have to find the best way to contact google for help with specific bugs. In this case the name I want to use is 'mywebsite-dot-com' and that auto-generates a project id that is identical ('mywebsite-dot-com').

Update: Google support did respond and let me know that '-dot-' is indeed a hidden keyword and cannot be used in the project ID.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the error was occurring because I was using my school email, which is technically a Google email, but maybe the school doesn't subscribe to all of Google's features or something. I logged in with my regular gmail account, and I was able to create a new project.